Change DNS name to Azure VM
I assigned a DNS name label to my VM. Now, I changed it with another one, and I want to assign the old one to another VM, but it says it is already in use.
Do you know how to do it?

To change the DNS name for an Azure VM, you need to ensure that the DNS name label you want to reuse is not currently assigned to any other VM. If you have changed the DNS name label for your existing VM, the old label may still be in use until the DNS settings propagate.
If you are encountering an error stating that the DNS name is already in use, it may be due to the DNS name label being cached or not fully released. By the way how long did you wait? - Ms doc says- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-faq#how-long-does-it-take-for-dns-changes-to-take-effect-

Found few MS docs for the same-   Create a fully qualified domain name for a VM in the Azure portal

Change DNS servers


Can you check the DNS name of the first VM (my VM)? If it's still showing the old DNS name, you may need to wait for DNS propagation, which can take up to 48 hours or more, although it typically occurs within a few hours. It's worth waiting a bit longer to see if the changes eventually propagate

I tried the same on my VMs, it's working fine. check if you have missed something or accidentally kept same name. It would be good if you could share some more details

If I understood your question correctly you have two VMs with you. Let's say OldVM and a NewVM.
Now this OldVM has a DNS name, let's say demoarko. You want to change this name to let's say demoarko1
and use the demoarko dns name in your NewVM.
The easiest way is to just go to your respective VMs from portal and under overview, click on your VM's public IP. It should open a page something like this-

Now as you can see we have dns name there demoarko
Let's change it to demoarko1

Done. No issues so far.
Now will use this demoarko dns name in my NewVM.
Same way goto that VM and click on it's public IP from portal-> overview section. It should open up a similar page.

And it accepted demoarko dns name (existing one which was on OldVM)
If I want to cross check it now from CLI level as well, I can see

it is reflecting. MS says

Found few additional MS docs-

Create a fully qualified domain name for a VM in the Azure portal
Change DNS servers


@andrea issue resolved?

Hello, sorry for my late reply. Yes, I solved the problem. Basically the 2 VMs were in different regions, and it did not allow me to change the dns name between the 2 machines. So, I had to create the new one in the same region and it worked.

Great to hear that @Andrea
